# Add Web.config as link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have one Web.config which should be used by two web applications. What can I do not to duplicate config?

I thought about an option to add Web.config as link to both projects. But the problem is that Web.config should not in the output folder but in the web application root (if I am not mistaken) and I don't see how I can achieve it with linked file.

Any other options?

Comment: You need the whole file, or just specific section like `appSettings`?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, currently I want to use the whole file

Comment: I fear it's not possible to tell the web application to take the `web.config` from different location. You can copy the file to the other location and build some basic tool that monitor the original file and update the other file whenever the original is changing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this to be linked on the production server or during development? You could link it using visual studio "Add Existing Item" > "Add As Link" if you only need it linked during development on you local machine. I know you mentioned something similar above, but you should be able to do this in the web root of the project.